# Which algorithm should I use in PHP to create hashed request for Telenor EasyPay?

Tags: payment-gateway, easypaisa, easypay

I am trying to integrate EasyPay with an online store. I am having "invalid request" problem both for staging and production accounts without hashing my request parameters. Now I am trying to hash all the parameters I am passing to EasyPay server but don't know which algorithm exactly I should use to hash my request.

Comment: can you please provide me api details ?

Comment: API is a simple HTML form post request to https://easypay.easypaisa.com.pk/easypay/Index.jsf or https://easypaystg.easypaisa.com.pk/easypay/Index.jsf. To make the request parameters more secure Easypay merchant account provide a hash key which can be used to encrypt all request parameters but in their official integration guide they don't mention which algorithm to use for encrypting parameters.

Comment: You can check here how has is generated: https://github.com/FahadYousafMahar/Easypay-WHMCS-Gateway/blob/master/EasyPay.php

Comment: Thanks for the link but I have tried that and their function mcrypt_encrypt()  is deprecated in PHP7.4+. I also used openssl_encrypt($string, 'aes-256-ctr', $hKey, $options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv); but it didn't work for me because the exact algorithm and block sizes have not been specified by Easypay.